# How do I update in ubuntu 20.4 with https// ... release not found error

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, https, mongodb-tools

I am trying to update my packages in ubuntu 20.4 but its not working and gives the error below

`Err:13 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/3.6.3 Release 404  Not Found [IP: 18.165.201.119 443]`

I have removed or uninstall mongodb from my packages or machine but still sees this error anytime I run

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt autoremove`

Can someone please help. Thank you all.

Comment: MongoDB 3.6 was last updated 2 years ago.  It's no longer supported in Ubuntu 20.04 and above.

Comment: Yes, that is what I learnt from other sources but the problem is how do i prevent this error from appearing anytime I run ``` sudo apt-get update```. As i said i don't even need mongodb on my system for now. All I want it a successful update.Thank you

Comment: "how do i prevent this error from appearing anytime I run 'sudo apt-get update'":  `grep -rs repo.mongodb.org /etc/apt` and rename/remove that source or comment-out corresponding lines

Comment: Bravo, it worked after I removed the files from the directories. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling the package does not delete the repository. The non existing repo path is what causes the error with apt. You can take a look into your list of repositories and remove it from there.

```
$ apt-add-repository --list
```

There you should be able to see it.

And now delete it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove <the-repository>
```

You can also remove the created sources file, which you'll find in:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/...
```

You might also want to remove remnants previously downloaded packages it in: (doesn't solve your issue, but cleans up)

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mongodb.*
```